# unresolved external symbol ...QueryInterface

Tags: c++, com, components

I have an unmanaged C++ class which has a com map inside of it. EX:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP
(MyClass)
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(...)
END_COM_MAP
```

But now from within the class if I try calling this->QueryInterface I get the following error:

`unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CTest::QueryInterface(struct _GUID const &,void * *)" (?QueryInterface@CTest@@UAGJABU_GUID@@PAPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CTest::CTest(void)" (??0CTest@@QAE@XZ)`

But now, if I try and implement a QueryInterface method I get the following error:

```
error C2535: 'HRESULT CTest::QueryInterface(const IID &,void **) throw()' : member function already defined or declared
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but the issue in the end seems to of been that I was trying to QueryInterface from the constructor. Once I moved it to a separate method everything worked fine.

Does anyone have any docs on why you cannot call QueryInterface from a constructor?

Comment: Regardless of whether you *can* call QueryInterface, it's a virtual function, so the standard advice *against* calling virtual methods from constructors applies.

Comment: QueryInterface (aka QI) is generally not called from constructors because it relies on the object having been fully constructed to work.  Objects are constructed from the base class out, and if the COM support is added on as a wrapper around a base class, QI will never work from any constructor along the inheritance chain.
So this stuff is usually done in a FinalConstruct or an Initialize method.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys. These were great explinations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not linking properly to the ATL lib files.  Check your project options in Visual Studio and make sure you are statically linking to ATL.

Comment: CTest::QueryInterface(struct _GUID const &,void * *) won't be an export of the ATL library files will it?